# Two custom tableViewCells in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to create a contacts page where you can see all your contacts with a friend request cell showing up when you receive a friend request, but not there when you do not have any. At the moment, both custom cells work fine. The issue I have is that the contactRequestTableViewCell overlaps the first cell of the contactListTableViewCell.

I have researched other questions about two custom tableviewcells and none are quite having the same issues that I am facing.

[image]

[image: This is what my storyboard looks like]

Here is my executing code at the moment, I am returning 2 sections in the table view.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ContactListTableViewCell
    let requestCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("requestCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ContactRequestsTableViewCell


    let user = OneRoster.userFromRosterAtIndexPath(indexPath: indexPath)


    if (amountOfBuddyRequests > 0) {


        if (indexPath.section == 0) {

            requestCell.hidden = false
            cell.hidden = false
            requestCell.friendRequestLabel.text = "test"


        } else if (indexPath.section >= 1) {

    cell.contactNameLabel!.text = user.displayName;
    cell.contactHandleLabel!.text = "@ " + beautifyJID(user.jidStr)
    cell.contactHandleLabel!.textColor = UIColor.grayColor()

    OneChat.sharedInstance.configurePhotoForImageView(cell.imageView!, user: user)
        }

        return cell;
    }

    else { // if buddy requests == 0
        requestCell.hidden = true



        cell.contactNameLabel!.text = user.displayName;
        cell.contactHandleLabel!.text = "@ " + beautifyJID(user.jidStr)
        cell.contactHandleLabel!.textColor = UIColor.grayColor()            

        print ("This is how many unreadMessages it has \(user.unreadMessages)")

        // If there is unread messages for a person highlight it blue
        // However this feature isn't working right now due to unreadMessages bug
        if user.unreadMessages.intValue > 0 {
            cell.backgroundColor = .blueColor()
        } else {
            cell.backgroundColor = .whiteColor()
        }

                OneChat.sharedInstance.configurePhotoForCell(cell, user: user)

        return cell;
    }


}
```

[image]

This is the current output that I have right now, my cells that have "test" are covering up other contactListTableViewCells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the issue was dealing with the data sources. My data sources were not pointing to the correct tableviewcell. This resulted in them pointing to an incorrect cell. This issue was fixed by remaking the data sources system that was in place. This issue will not affect most as the data sources will point to the correct tableviewcell by default.

Contrary to what another poster said, you can in fact display two or more custom cells in a single table. This is how I fixed the tableView display issues:

```
var friendRequests = ["FriendRequest1", "FriendRequest2"]
var contacts = ["User1","User2","User3","User4"]
var amountOfBuddyRequests = 1


 override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if (amountOfBuddyRequests > 0) {
        return 2
    }

    return 1
}




override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if (amountOfBuddyRequests > 0) {
        if (section == 0) {
            return friendRequests.count
        }

    }
  return contacts.count




override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {



    if (amountOfBuddyRequests > 0) {
        if (indexPath.section == 0) {
            let requestCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("requestCell") as! ContactRequestsTableViewCell

            requestCell.friendRequestLabel.text = friendRequests[indexPath.row]
            requestCell.onButtonTapped = {
                self.friendRequests.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
            requestCell.addButtonTapped = {
                self.addUser(self.friendRequests[indexPath.row])
                self.friendRequests.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }


            return requestCell
        }
    }


    let friendCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FriendCell") as! ContactListTableViewCell
    friendCell.contactNameLabel.text = contacts[indexPath.row]




    return friendCell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` should always return **one and the only one** TableViewCell you want at `indexPath`, so you don't want to always return `cell` of type `ContactListTableViewCell`.

According to [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:), the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` tableView method asks for the cell at the indexPath, which means literally there can only be one cell at certain row of a certain section, so returning two cells is not an option.

I suggest you use two arrays to store the requests and contacts information. For example, you have arrays `requests` and `contacts`. Then you can tell the tableView how many rows you want:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return requests.count + contacts.count
}
```

and then in `cellForRowAtIndexpath` you do something like:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row < requests.count {
        // return a request cell
    }
    else {
        // return a contact cell
    }
}
```

I'm only using one tableView section here. If you still want two sections you can simply return 2 in `numberOfSections` function and add if statements in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` for `indexPath.section`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Using this solution, I would only be able to return one cell at a time correct? I want to be able to return both a requestCell and a contactCell at the same in the tableViewtime if there are requests.

Comment: Yes, you would only be able to return one cell at a time. This method won't "delay" you in any way as long as you update the table after you get the data for requests. I don't think one can return two cells in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`